# Characters for Taiwanese

Tags: characters, cantonese, traditional-characters, resources, taiwanese

As far as I know, Cantonese has its associated characters. But as I searched for Taiwanese characters, I only find the pinyin system to indicate the pronunciation of words, such as:

> 遮雨 **jia-hōo/lia-hōo**

Are there characters for Taiwanese?

Comment: What do you mean by "character set"? In what sense? A computer one like BIG-5 or UTF-8? A writing input system like Cangjie where each part of a character is represented separately? Not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: I thought BIG-5 and UTF-8 are character encodings. Thanks for pointing out though. I'll edit my question.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Written_Hokkien

Comment: I'm confused by the question. 遮雨 _does_ represent the Taiwanese characters for j(l)ia-hōo.

Comment: Hmm...I thought it's a Mandarin equivalent or Mandarin representation of `j(l)ia-hōo`? I could be wrong though.

Comment: What do you mean by ”taiwanese”? Amis, Paiwan or some other native tongue? They have neither characters nor any written language at all.

If you mean Minnan or Mandarin, they are not ”taiwanese” languages, but Chinese topolects.

Comment: [This](http://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/mobile/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how well it's implemented but you can check this out:

[台湾闽南语推荐用字](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E8%87%BA%E7%81%A3%E9%96%A9%E5%8D%97%E8%AA%9E%E6%8E%A8%E8%96%A6%E7%94%A8%E5%AD%97)

> ## 台湾闽南语推荐用字
>
> 台湾闽南语推荐用字为台湾闽南语书写系统的汉字建议用字表，实施单位为中华民国教育部。
>
> ## 简介
>
> 台湾闽南语推荐用字于2009年9月中发布完700个字，并发布于教育部国语推行委员会（国语会）[1](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E8%87%BA%E7%81%A3%E9%96%A9%E5%8D%97%E8%AA%9E%E6%8E%A8%E8%96%A6%E7%94%A8%E5%AD%97)的网站，免费供一般社会人士与学生等下载运用。
>
> 台湾官方以4年时间整理的用字，第一批闽南语推荐用字于2007年5月30日颁布，共有300字[2](http://www.edu.tw/pages/detail.aspx?Node=3682&Page=25954&Index=9&WID=C5AD5187-55EF-4811-8219-E946FE04F725)， 2008年5月1日公布第2批100字[3](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/700iongji_1031222.pdf)， 2009年10月2日公布最后一批300字[4](http://www.edu.tw/pages/detail.aspx?Node=3682&Page=25954&Index=9&WID=C5AD5187-55EF-4811-8219-E946FE04F725)。这700个字基本上已经标准化了台湾闽南语用字。未来如果有需要再增加推荐用字的话，国语会会再补。
>   国语会选字标准
>
> 选用字之时，国语会的标准如下[6](http://www.edu.tw/FileUpload/3677-15601/Documents/300iongji_960523.pdf)：
>
> 使用本字：台湾传统闽南语文所用汉字多为传统用字，例如“山”、“水””、“天”。偶尔，台湾闽南语用字与古汉语一致，例如“箸”（筷子）、“沃”（浇）、“行”（走）、“走”（跑）、“倩”（雇用）、“晏”（晚）、“青盲”（失明）、“才调”（本事）等。
>       训用字（训读字）：若是台湾闽南语本字不清楚，而现代标准汉语用字接近台湾闽南语字音与字意，则采用训用字，例如“戆”（gōng）、“挖”（óo/ué）、“会”（ē）等。
>       借音字：若是台湾闽南语本字不清楚，再加上现代标准汉语用字不接近闽南语字意，而民间习惯使用音接近之字，则采用借音字，例如“嘛”（mā，也）、“佳哉”（ka-tsài，幸亏）、“磅空”（pōng-khang，隧道）等。
>
> 现况上也配合台湾每县市1到3位乡土语言指导员，来帮助台湾闽南语的语言政策并藉以研发乡土语言等课程发展。
>   台湾闽南语常用词辞典
>
> 2008年10月17日公布《台湾闽南语常用词辞典》（试用版），收录一万六千个常用闽南语词汇及单音字[7](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/700iongji_1031222.pdf)。2009年10月国语会有计划出版《台湾闽南语常用词辞典》。
>
> ## 用字举例
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> ## 问题与建议
>
> 2011年在教育部召开公听会检讨首部官方版闽南语辞典时，桃园社区大学刘志鸿表示，发布的七百个推荐字当中的四百多字有待商榷，有争议的用字不宜贸然推行到学校教学及编成辞典。例如：
>
> 意为贫穷人的“散凶（散乡）人”、“散赤（散食）人”、“瘦呷（瘦吃）人”。
>
> 而台中市海洋台语文研究学会理事长林绍良则认为，至少有一成要检讨修订，举例：
>
> 蚂蚁非哺乳类动物，“狗蚁”建议应作“蚼蚁”；
>      “公公、婆婆”依传统古汉字应写成“唐官、唐家”。[9](http://www.edu.tw/pages/detail.aspx?Node=3682&Page=25954&Index=9&WID=C5AD5187-55EF-4811-8219-E946FE04F725)

you can download the following pdfs:

[台湾闽南语推荐用字（第1批）](http://www.edu.tw/FileUpload/3677-15601/Documents/300iongji_960523.pdf)

[台湾闽南语推荐用字（第2批）](http://www.edu.tw/FileUpload/3677-15601/Documents/100iongji_970501.pdf)

[台湾闽南语推荐用字（第3批）](http://www.edu.tw/FileUpload/3677-15601/Documents/300iongji_3rd_990915.pdf)

MoE's [department of lifelong education](http://www.edu.tw/pages/detail.aspx?Node=3682&Page=25954&Index=9&WID=C5AD5187-55EF-4811-8219-E946FE04F725) also has a bunch of downloadable pdfs:

> 臺灣閩南語推薦用字
>
> 1. 臺灣閩南語[卡拉OK正字字表](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/minkalaok_970501.pdf)及內[容說明](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/minkalaokintro_970501.pdf)
> 2. 臺灣閩南語[推薦用字700字詞](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/700iongji_1031222.pdf)
> 3. 臺灣閩南語推薦用字隨手冊[(1)](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/book-one-sided-1031222.pdf) [(2)](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/book-two-sided-1031222.pdf)、字卡[(3)](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/card-one-sided-1031222.pdf) [(4)](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/card-two-sided-1031222.pdf) 及[製作說明(5)](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/userguide.pdf)
>
> (1) [手冊單面列印](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/book-one-sided-1031222.pdf)
>
> (2) [手冊雙面列印](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/book-two-sided-1031222.pdf)
>
> (3) [字卡單面列印](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/card-one-sided-1031222.pdf)
>
> (4) [字卡雙面列印](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/card-two-sided-1031222.pdf)
>
> (5) [製作說明](http://www.edu.tw/userfiles/file/iongji/userguide.pdf)

Answer (score -2):

Chinese characters are divided into traditional Chinese and simple Chinese. Simple Chinese is used in the mainland China and traditional Chinese is used in Hong Kong and Taiwan. Before the People's Republic of China, traditional Chinese are also used in mainland China. But after the foundation of People's Republic of China, simple Chinese are set for increasing literacy. As for 遮雨，it is used in Taiwan and mainland China at the same time. Because, some simple and traditional Chinese are same. For example, 書 → 书 the first one is the traditional and the second one is simple. The tradtional characters are more complicated than simple ones. I am a Chinese teacher from hanbridgemandarin and hope my answer can help you.